# Passing cli parameters to casperjs through grunt task and npm test

Tags: npm, gruntjs, casperjs

I'm running tests with `npm test` - that actually runs a grunt task `grunt casperjs`:

```
casperjs:{
            options:{},
            files:
                ['./test_index.js',
                './test_map_regression.js',
                './test_index_get_gush.js'] /

        },
```

using the [grunt-casperjs-plugin](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-casperjs-plugin) in order to automate testing with slimerjs along with phantomjs, both running under casperjs in Travis-ci.

In order to do that, I need to pass the engine as a variable from the command line. something like:

```
casperjs --engine=slimerjs test_suite.js
```

**Question:** I can't find a way to pass the options from grunt cli (and I assume npm command line options would delegate to grunt. correctly?) to the `files` array.

I tried to add:

```
var engine = grunt.option('engine') || 'phantomjs';
    engine = '--engine='+engine;
```

and then in the file array do:

```
files:['./test_index.js '+engine,
    './test_map_regression.js '+enging,
    './test_index_get_gush.js '+engine]
```

but seems that file array has to get real file names without the added args.

I'll be glad for any ideas on how to solve this through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but looking at the [grunt-casperjs source](https://github.com/ronaldlokers/grunt-casperjs/blob/master/tasks/lib/casperjs.js), it looks as though you would want to pass the engine as an option.

So, something like this should work:

```
casperjs:{
    options: {
        'engine': 'slimerjs'
    },
    files: [
        './test_index.js',
        './test_map_regression.js',
        './test_index_get_gush.js'
    ]
}
```

Comment: This sent me in the right direction. Also I had to hack [grunt-casperjs source](https://github.com/ronaldlokers/grunt-casperjs/blob/master/tasks/lib/casperjs.js) to make it recognize the ```--engine``` option